# Table artifacts from django forms.Charfield

Tags: html, django, django-views

I'm using a CharField in a forms.Form subclass:

```
search_term = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CharField())
```

It seems to render and work fine but I see table artifacts `<tr>,<th>,<td>` in the resulting html:

```
    <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="xxxx">
      <tr>
    <th><label for="id_search_term">Search term:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="search_term" value="" required id="id_search_term">     
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I'm hoping to clean the html up a bit.  All ideas welcome!